Is a free algebra the tensor product of the original ring $R$ and the semigroup of all generating words?
Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Do we have $R\langle X\rangle=R \otimes_\mathbb{Z} W$, where $W$ is the free semigroup of $X$? I want to know if, under this context, the tensor product is well-defined? It seems ok to me, but just wants to check. Thanks in advance.

How do you tensor a ring with a semigroup?

@Tzimmo As the accepted answer suggests, what I missed is I can't directly tensor product $R$ with $W$, but have to do so for $R$ with the free abelian group generated by $W$.

No, there is no definition for the tensor product of a ring and a semigroup.
It is true that $R\left<X\right> = R \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Z}\left<X\right>$, and also that $R\left<X\right>$ is the semigroup algebra of $W$ over $R$ (which is defined similarly to the group algebra, and has similar universal property).
Also, there is usually a difference between the free monoid (which does contain the empty word) and the free semigroup (which does not). Here we actually need $W$ to be the free monoid.

Thanks. Can I think of $\mathbb{Z}\langle X\rangle$ as the free abelian group generated by free semigroup generated by $X$, coupled with a definition of multiplication that is compatible with word concatenation?

Yes, it is exactly that

I made an edit about terminology, we need the free monoid, not the free semigroup.

"No, there is no definition for the tensor product of a ring and a semigroup." - For sure there is. You just wrote it down. Also, it can be defined without reference to the free algebra (over Z), and also works in great generality. I can also tensor an abelian group with a monoid, for example. For more details see Freyd's paper on representable functors.

@MartinBrandenburg Could you please give a more precise reference? What is the category in which we define these tensor products?

@VladimirLysikov I suspect maybe there is a tensor product defined for abelian semigroups. Then just define a multiplication compatible.
